# Mobile website and desktop website : do I have to duplicate my code?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, symfony, responsive-design

I have a website built with Symfony2 and I would like to create a mobile version of it using jQuery mobile (I'm currently using Twitter bootstrap for the desktop version).

I'm really confused about the solution I have to choose :

- create a subdomain, for example : http://mobile.mywebsite.com and create another Symfony project which would be very similar but with just other html.twig files (to integrate jQuery mobile), but that means that I would duplicate a big part of my code ?
- media queries inside my symfony project in html files to use jquery mobile elements according to screen size. Thus, I would have only one project to maintain.

Any advice would be great ! Thanks !

Comment: Why create two projects?  You are using Twitter Bootstrap which allows for responsive UI.  Why not just improve your Twitter Bootstrap CSS and tweak your Symfony2 backend to make the website responsive?

Comment: I was thinking that jQuery mobile offers more possibilities such as switching elements in a list just flipping with the hand etc...that it was more like a native app

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to mix the two platforms together unless you built your Symphony2 architecture to be RESTFUL service.  If Symphony2 serves up a lot of views then I would not go down the jQuery mobile route.  Mashing those two platforms together will hurt a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do routing based on the domain name:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

With this you can have different controllers for the mobile site but still re-use your model and (at least some of) your view. You could even re-use some of the controllers by setting a parameter (based on the host) in the routing and then using that in the controllers:

```
# routing.yml

mobile_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     m.{domain}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage, mobileVersion: true }
    requirements:
        domain: %domain%

homepage:
    path:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage }
```

Then in your controller:

```
// Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/MainController.php

public function homepageAction($mobileVersion = false) {
  ...
  if ($mobileVersion) {
    // do some mobile things, perhaps return a specific template
  } else {
    // do some non-mobile things, perhaps return a specific template
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to create one page with a responsive design (media queries are part of that) that can adapt to any screen size.

You definitely should not be making a second Symfony project. You are essentially trying to make 2 different layouts for your site, so they should only affect your view. If you don't want to use a responsive design, you can create twig templates for your mobile pages and load those from the same controllers you use for the desktop site.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but it still may be usefull for others.

I had the same question this morning and Google gave me MobileDetectBundle https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle/ which seems to solve that kind of problem. Not tryed yet but I will for sure !